# Handling empty lists - better to use ListFragment or Fragment+ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment, adapter

I have some doubts. I'm trying to make an application with lists. I made one but with a ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter and ListView.

Then I realized that there is also ListFragment. And with the fragments you can easily display messages "empty list". What I want to do is a list of items and each item associated with this single_item.xml for example. I have seen several examples, but there are differences between them and me is not good either choose from.

Which is the updated method  to do this and has the best performance? Are ListFragment better than ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Are ListFragment better than ListAdapter` hmmm is the spoon better than the ball? did you mean ListView vs ListView from ListFragment? still it is hard to compare

Answer (score 2):

[`ListFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) essentially provides shortcuts for interacting with a Fragment whose layout contains a single ListView (and nothing else, by default). The ListFragment does not provide any performance advantage, as far as I know. You can inspect the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/app/ListFragment.java#ListFragment) if you would like to know more about how the class functions.

My preference is to avoid ListFragments - I find them inflexible if the layout of a screen ever needs to change, plus they use slightly differently-named APIs that can be somewhat fiddly to remember (onListItemClick, vs the onItemClick callback of a standard AdapterView, for example).

[Here is a good article](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/06/20/listview-tips-tricks-1-handle-emptiness/) that describes how to handle empty ListViews. You are looking for the [`setEmptyView(View)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView(android.view.View)) method of ListView. This allows you to specify the view to be displayed when the ListView is empty.

Comment: so if I want to make a list and when it is empty. I still use my ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter and ListView + a Fragment to show a message That the list is empty? (sorry my English is bad)

Comment: Yep, that's definitely possible. [Here is a good article](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/06/20/listview-tips-tricks-1-handle-emptiness/) that describes how to handle empty ListViews. You are looking for the [`setEmptyView(View)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView(android.view.View)) method of ListView. Copying this comment in to main answer also.

Comment: But the example is with ViewStub. It's the same way width Fragments?

Comment: The ViewStub in that example represents the view to be displayed when the ListView is empty. Cyril's example is using a ListActivity with a customized layout (to be able to include the empty layout) which is analogous to a ListFragment. If you provide the empty view in your ListFragment's xml layout, as he has, you can provide any View subclass for the empty view. If you instead use a regular Fragment + ListView, the same applies - setEmptyView can take any View subclass as an argument, so you are not constrained to using ViewStub.